# Why Shared Value in Python Creates Extra Processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, shared-memory

Normally when I spawn new process, I will have just 1 in-process python code.
But when I use shared memory (shared value), Python will create another new process beside of my own process.

Sample (shows 1 process):

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mytarget)
p.daemon = True
p.start()
```

Sample (shows 2 processes while I spawned just 1 process):

```
shared = Manager().Value(int, 0)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mytarget, args=(shared))
p.daemon = True
p.start()
```

Is there any way to avoid creating new extra processes in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) documentation calling `Manager()` creates separate server process that is responsible for managing objects shared in that manager. So this is that extra process you can see.

I did not go through documentation very carefully, but you could try alternative way to use shared memory  i.e. [shared ctypes objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) like [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) or [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array)

Comment: Thank you so much!